# Powershell command Get-MgdriveitemChild does not allow filtering out files or folders

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Powershell command Get-MgDriveItemChild belongs to Microsoft.Graph.Files module.  It returns a list of child items in the specified container.  However, filtering out files or folders doesn't work.  I'm running the latest version of the Microsoft.Graph.Files module (1.10.0).

$assumring subitems contains a list of files and folders

```
## This does not filter out folders
$subitems = Get-MgDriveItemChild -DriveId $drive.id -DriveItemId $targetItem.id -All 
$files = $subitems | Where-Object { $_.folder -eq $null }

## This also does not  filter out folders
$subitems = Get-MgDriveItemChild -DriveId $drive.id -DriveItemId $targetItem.id -All - Filter 'Folder eq null'
```

For the sake of brevity, I have tried filtering out files and folders in different variations, but doesn't work. I tried ChatGpt and Google Bard and both confirm that this is a bug.  I'm surprised it has not been addressed.

Comment: You can report the issue here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues

Comment: "I tried ChatGpt and Google Bard and both confirm that this is a bug." - LLMs will confirm you're the King of France if you ask them insistingly enough. Have you investigated whether a `folder` property exists on the items (with `Get-Member` for example)?